# Search Bar with Array

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the search bar with an array

```
void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Repositorio repo = new Repositorio();
            Cliente[] listacliente = repo.getCliente();
            List<Cliente> lst = listacliente.OfType<Cliente>().ToList();
            var ClienteSearched = lst.Where(l => l.Contains(SearchBar.Text));
            ListaClientes.ItemsSource = ClienteSearched;
        }
```

but it is not working, i would like to know if there is way to make it works

this is the class

````
public class Cliente
    {
        [JsonProperty("Cliente1")]
        public string Cliente1 { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Correo { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Calle { get; set; }
        public string Hab { get; set; }
        public string Ciudad { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Zip { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```
and this is the error


Error   CS1929
````

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Are you getting an error or exception?  Have you stepped through the code to verify that each line is doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: it will be interesting to have the definition of Cliente Class

Comment: I edited the question and posted the class and error number, thanks

Comment: ok, which line is the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cliente` does not have a `Contains` method.  You need to call `Contains` on one of `Cliente`'s string properties, like this

```
var ClienteSearched = lst.Where(l => l.Cliente1.Contains(SearchBar.Text));
```